# What is a good way to handle hierarchies in dimension tables

Tags: data-modeling, data-warehouse, business-intelligence, obiee

Is there any good approach for designing dimensional table/tables for hierarchical data (similar to employee-manager relation) with inconsistent deep level hierarchy.

Thanks,
Ravi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about Parent-Child hierarchies, where the relationship is recursive? OBIEE supports these natively, see [documentation here](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/biee/BIEMG/GUID-0424E7A7-C7DB-447A-B0C4-0BD6790888EA.htm#GUID-0DABD43C-3364-4590-95EF-330F62AB12C9).

Comment: Thank you . I will look into it